# Add from the 5th value

Tags: mysql, sql

### The goal

Add from the 5th value.

### The problem

There is a table on my database called `markets`.  Within it, there are 5 values:

```
+----+------+
| Id | Name |
+----+------+
| 0  | NULL |
+----+------+
| 1  | A    |
+----+------+
| 2  | B    |
+----+------+
| 3  | C    |
+----+------+
| 4  | D    |
+----+------+
```

`Id` is a primary key and auto-incremented column and its start by zero (I added it manually to use as default). When I add some market to this table, seems that MySQL adds the market in question with `0` as `Id` — and I want to set the `Id` as `5` to continue the table's logic. So I ask: **how can I add some value from the 5th `Id`?**

### What I've already tried

I already set the `auto_increment` value for `5`, but without success. The query that I used is the following:

```
ALTER TABLE `markets` AUTO_INCREMENT = 5;
```

### How do I know that the MySQL is attempting to add the market with its `Id` as `0`?

My application is powered by C# that is throwing an exception:

> Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Are you certain that your C# code isn't trying to explicitly supply a zero there? What query are you executing from C#?  Things like non-numeric strings will cast to zero, a NULL keyword in the language may cast to zero in some string contexts...

Comment: When you're inserting, are you intentionally adding `0` or are you leaving it blank?

Comment: Just do `INSERT INTO markets (Name) VALUES ('E');`.

Comment: `show create table markets` will show you exactly what the auto_increment "next value to be used" is as part of the table arguments. you can check if the alter query is going through using that.

Comment: "Id is a primary key and auto-incremented column and its start by zero (I added it manually to use as default)." How?

Comment: @Strawberry I just added a new market whose its Id is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `INSERT` statement, leave the `auto_increment` field out of the statement. This will leave MySQL to increment it and add it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> **how can I add some value from the 5th Id**

Just try:;--

```
INSERT INTO markets(Name) VALUES('E');
```

ie, dont use the `auto_increment` field while inserting the data. MySQL is smart enough to do that for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Already there are four values are there in the table, So you can just insert next row. it will automatically take 5 as a next value.

When we are using auto_increment no need to specify that column in the insert command.

```
INSERT INTO markets(Name) VALUES('E');
```

In case if you want to alter the auto_increment value you can use the following statement

```
ALTER TABLE market AUTO_INCREMENT = 5;
```